# Suffering from a third world country academic culture

Tags: graduate-school, graduate-admissions

I live in a third world country where I have no chance of getting into good graduate schools in my country for MS CS which are tickets to US Ph.D  programs. I am not a perfectionist but other schools have no connections with current research community or professors there have no idea how to write a recommendation letter.

***Problems***:

Working full time, no chance to relocate to other city or job. I always get a biased approach from professors here when I approach for collaboration as an outsider. Impossible to get into their MS programs for me so I have no chance for getting some research experience or any recommendation letters.

What should I do ? I am continuously doing self study on some topics but biased approach and discrimination in my country gives me no chance. I have started to think of completely burning all my books and other stuff because all my efforts are useless going nowhere purely based on where I live.

Do you have any suggestions? Is there a way to find a professor outside this system lacking funding or student, with whom I can work remotely? I can work for free if it comes down to it.

Comment: I down voted this question because _no chance to relocate to other city or job_ **and** _I can work for free_ **do not** add up.

Comment: People might have personal reasons for not having a chance to relocate, such as a family.

Comment: @xepebo Would you care to explain why it is impossible to get into the MS programs in your place?

Comment: Whatever you decide, please do not burn the books. Sell them, give them away - just don't burn them.

Comment: ...better yet, scan them and _then_ burn them.

Comment: possibly even better... scan them, print them and burn the printouts.

Comment: It would also help to give what kind of discrimination you are facing, is it based on gender/religion/ethnicity/social status..? There might be ways to tackle discrimination, even though I can imagine that in some places that'd be pretty difficult.

Answer (score 13):

This is an outside possibility, but, have you considered enrolling as an external student at an overseas university?

Admittedly, I am not sure of US universities, but ones here in Australia often have a large proportion of external students - with delivery given online and/or by post (usually the former).  An example is the university I am enrolled in (in Queensland) - I completed my MSc while I lived in Tokyo, Japan.

Just wanted to add - don't burn the books and especially don't give up (but understand the feeling, albeit from a different viewpoint).  I commend you on your self-discipline and determination - these traits will hold you in good stead when you find your path.